# Updating parent entity without changing the children

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a one-to-many relationship... I am working in a web environment (disconnected environment). Imagine user wanting to update only the parent entity, without having to load all the child entities, is it possible?

This is the code:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public Parent Parent { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

I want to update description of `Parent` with id = 5, the new description is coming from User:

```
Parent parent = new Parent()
{
    Id = 5, // I already know the user Id
    Description = "new description from User";
    Children = null; // I don't want the children to be changed
}

dbContext.Parent.Attach(parent);
dbContext.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I am not sure if this is the right approch? will existing `Children` be deleted (since the children list is null)?

Comment: You can actually get "Parent" from your dbContext using the Id(5) > Update the description > straight to dbContext.SaveChanges().
or you want an example of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible?

**Yes**, you are doing right.

According to your sample

```
dbContext.Parent.Attach(parent);
dbContext.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

It just effects on `parent` table only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried running the code and set the child list to null... it did not delete the child records. I have removed the link that you had pot as reference, as it was not really related to this question.

Comment: Note that this is no longer valid for ef core 6